# Array of hooks in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm starting to use hooks in React and I got stuck, when I realized I would need an array of hooks to solve my problem. But according to the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)

> Only Call Hooks at the Top Level

I'm not allow to call hooks inside a loop (and I guess also not in `map`).

My custom hook subscribes to an API and adds data to the state when there is an update:

```
export const useTrace = (id) => {
  [trace, setTrace] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    Api.getCurrentTrace(id)
      .then(currentTrace => {
        setTrace(currentTrace)
      })
  }, [id])
  
  useEffect(() => {
    Api.subscribeTraceUpdate(onUpdateTrip)
    
    return () => {
      Api.unsubscribeTraceUpdate(onUpdateTrip)
    }
  }, [])

  const onUpdateTrip = msg => {
    if (msg.id === id) {
      setTrace([msg.data].concat(trace))
    }
  }
}
```

In my component I have a state with an array of IDs. For each ID I would like to use the `useTrace(id)` hook somehow like this:

```
import DeckGL from '@deck.gl/react'

function TraceMap({ ids }) {
  const data = ids.map((id) => ({
    id,
    path: useTrace(id)
  }))

  const pathLayer = new PathLayer({
    id: 'path-layer',
    data,
    getPath: d => d.path
  })

  return <DeckGL
    layers={[ pathLayer ]}
  />
}
```

For the sake of simplicity I got `ids` as a property instead of having a state.

Comment: Maybe think about doing this in a more performant process. If you are using arrays to update state on any change instead do a test and compare the array data rather than your current intention.

Answer (score 1):

Why not have a `useTraces` custom hook rather than `useTrace`. This new hook can take an array of ids instead of a single id.

```
export const useTraces = (ids) => {
  [traces, setTraces] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const traces = await Promise.all(
        ids.map((id) => Api.getCurrentTrace(id))
      );
      setTraces(traces);
    })();
  }, [ids]);

  // ... 
};
```

Comment: I'm using that hook also in an other component, where I only need the trace of an single ID. I agree, having a `useTraces` hook would solve that problem. The way you expressed it, would create an `Api.getCurrentTraces` call for every ID, when only one ID is added or removed.

Comment: You can further optimise this hook to only send requests for changed ids. Regarding the other component, you can just send an array of single id.

Comment: I hoped that there is a way to use reacts mechanism somehow, where it compares the old IDs (keys) with the new ones and only update objects where the ID (key) changed.